# Several instances of Log4PHP in one single location

Tags: php, log4j, logging, log4php

Here is the scenario:

1. I have multiple servers and all of them are in different locations (not on the same network)
2. I need to log all errors from all of them in one single file.
3. Need to use Log4PHP - http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/configuration.html

I have been through the documentation and it seems to be very straight forward, therefore I haven't found a place that exemplify how to set Log4PHP in multiple instances (servers) and log into a single location.

In a visual interpretation this is how it should look like:

Server1 -> FileLocation1 
Server2 -> FileLocation1 
Server3 -> FileLocation1

Anyone has faced this or something similar with Log4PHP that I can use the experience as reference?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The natural thing to get log messages across a network would be to use syslog. The syslog server will write the messages to a file, and all three logging machines are only sending the messages to their own syslog system. It needs to be propery configured, though.

Logging into a database basically has the same effect, but is not really optimized for logging. If you experience heavy load, this might fail for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probobly this is not the right way of doing it, but i would:

From all 3 servers send log to logserver's database

then on logserver cron job to write in a one file

Comment: Interesting Idea. I need a single location and I have disconsidered the database. If I can configure it to the db, it might solve the issue. Reading from the db and sending an email on FATAL exceptions might be simpler. Great answer. Thanks.